# can you make textures in magicavoxel?

Tags: 3d, texture, pixel-art, art, magicavoxel

I'm working on a project that allows the player to purchase different skins. Can you make textures in MagicaVoxel? If not what are some good programs to make textures? I aiming to make blocky 3d textures for the skins that I can turn into a material to manipulate in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Magica Voxel exports to `.fbx` and `.obj` with a *single* ***long*** *strip* texture image, and has a general Atlas-like UV unwrap which applies that strip of colours to the geometry.

It's kinda... dumb... texturing as it's a PIA to work with elsewhere.

However, it should be pretty easy to work with in Unity, if the intent is to keep a similar feel there to what you set up in Magica Voxel. I've not tried it in Unity yet, though I spend a fair amount of time working in Unity - so I'll hafta try it and see how it does.

**Of note:** the polys themselves don't have independent material tags on them - they're all *one* material, and it's the position of the colour block on the strip and the relevant UV alignment that determines colour: you can, I'm sure, use the free Pro Builder tools to re-material-tag polys as you see fit in Unity, but bear in mind that will be a wholly manual process.

One plus of the one long strip texture image approach is that creating new variant skins shouldn't be terribly difficult!

Hope that helps some.